# GNOME unable to install extention

Tags: gnome-shell-extension, gnome-shell

I have been having an issue with downloading extensions due to an error message *Unable to locate GNOME Shell settings or version. Make sure it is installed and running.*

[image]

I have *GNOME Shell 3.10.4*
I also have the gnome shell extension for chrome working.What could i be missing?

Answer (score 2):

You have to be running GNOME Shell when looking to add/change GNOME extensions.

If you are running GNOME Shell, and still having problems, then...

You need to install this:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install chrome-gnome-shell
```

and then add this web browser add-on, if it's not already there:

```
GNOME Shell Integration 8.2.1
```

Comment: For clarity, if I'm in Unity does this mean I can't use gnome-shell extensions?

Comment: @Jonathan  No, you can't run GNOME Shell or GNOME Shell extensions, under Unity.